# Taking a list of stings and converting them in to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of strings and I want to convert them into a list of tuples. They all have a time prefix that ends with `- b`. I want to convert the string into a tuple consisting of the time (header) and the data (tail).

**Edit:**

I did try to covert the list into a list of lists:

```
for i in b:
   c.append(re.split(R,b[i]))
```

**String example:** `Sun Nov 17 04:38:17 +0000 2019 - b'RT  <data>`
and I would like the result in (time, data).

My data is being stored in a .txt file and I am using the `open()` and `readlines()` to extract the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? Are you aware of `str.split()`? Do you know how to do a list comprehension? If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: It wont let me do str.split() because I have a list of strings and I dont know how to list comprehension.

Comment: provide sample input and the expected output and a [mre]

Comment: See also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Rutchtus It sounds like you need to learn Python then. SO is not meant for tutorials or walkthroughs; we assume you already know the language. You could maybe could try [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Don't get me wrong I know a fair a bit of python I am just not familiar with list comprehensions.

Comment: could you also show what you expect the outcome to be? I understand you want them to be `(time, data)`, but how exactly that would look when you use the string sample you have given? `('Sun Nov 17 04:38:17 +0000 2019 - b', 'RT  <data>')`? and what is that quotation mark between `b'R`, is that a literal quotation mark?

Comment: better show example data - list with strings - (as text) and expected result. And then we can simply copy it and use to test solutions.

Comment: if time has constant length then you could simply slice it `time = line[:30]`, `data = line[30:]`. And it has to run in `for`-loop

Comment: if time ends with `- b` then you could use normal `str.split()` like `time, data = line.split("- b")`. And it has to run in `for`-loop

Comment: Re: "_I am just not familiar with list comprehensions_". Then see the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or any of [this 56.000 SO posts](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+list+comprehension) mentioning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time ends with `- b` then you could use normal `str.split("- b")` to get parts. And you would have to run it in loop

```
results = []

for line in all_lines:
    parts = line.split(' - b')
    results.append( parts )
```

or if you want to modify `time` or `data`

```
results = []

for line in all_lines:
    time, data = line.split(' - b')
    # ... here modify `time` or `data`
    results.append( [time, data] )
```

---

If time has constant length then you could use slice `line[:30]`

```
results = []

for line in all_lines:
    time = line[:30]
    data = line[30+4:]  # len(" - b") == 4
    results.append( [time,data] )
```

---

Minimal working example

```
all_lines = [
    "Sun Nov 17 04:38:17 +0000 2019 - b'RT  <data>",
    "Sun Nov 18 05:38:17 +0000 2020 - b'RT  <data>",
    "Sun Nov 19 06:38:17 +0000 2021 - b'RT  <data>",
]

results = []

for line in all_lines:
    #time, data = line.split(' - b')
    #results.append( [time, data] )

    #parts = line.split(' - b')
    #results.append( parts )
    
    time = line[:30]
    data = line[30+4:]  # len(" - b") == 4
    results.append( [time,data] )
    
# ---

#print(results)

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
['Sun Nov 17 04:38:17 +0000 2019', "'RT  <data>"]
['Sun Nov 18 05:38:17 +0000 2020', "'RT  <data>"]
['Sun Nov 19 06:38:17 +0000 2021', "'RT  <data>"]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Sorry for my bad syntax, I am still new to StackOverflow and to the online coding community in general. Your post helped me a lot!